# How can solve error while using 'create-react-native-app myProject' command?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-install

$ npm -v

**1.3.10**

$ node -v

**v9.2.0**

OS : Ubuntu 14.04

Following is the result when I use above command.
I followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) documentation.

npm ERR! 404 'expo' is not in the npm registry.

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-59-generic

npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "--save-exact" "react-native-scripts"

npm ERR! cwd /home/pithani/Project

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25

npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10

npm ERR! code E404

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xdl/-/xdl-46.0.1.tgz

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/pithani/Project/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0

`npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-native-scripts` failed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is with

```
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25

npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
```

This is a very old version of node and npm, possibly a version that came with ubuntu.

You should remove that old version of node, and check that the latest version of node is installed correctly.